# Saving a Navbar Shiny App In Rmarkdown

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, r-markdown, dt

I'm trying to save a Shiny app inside of an Rmarkdown file as a standalone HTML page.

I can do this with a simple DT::datatable():

````
---
title: "Test4"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r t4, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
DT::datatable(iris)
````

followed by

```
rmarkdown::render(input = "Test4.Rmd", output_file = "Test4.html", runtime = "shiny")
```

gives me an html file with the iris dataset and I can stick that out on a file server as needed. `$Employer` loves it and big ups to Joe Cheng et al for pointing me to that solution.

(
*Also, Joe Cheng sent this on the google Shiny group:
If you have just a `DT::datatable()` object (call it "x"), then you can call `htmlwidgets::saveWidget(x, "filepath.html")` to save it as an HTML page*
)

However, `$employer` has now requested that I put two of these together in a tabbed format.

When I use this code, the Rmd page renders correctly if I use the "Run Document" from RStudio:

````
---
title: "Test3"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Embedded Application

Test To Try and Render This Out As Standalone Tabbed Shiny App With Two DT::Dataframes.

```{r tabsets, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
shinyApp(
  ui <- (
  navbarPage(
  title = 'Testing Saving Shiny',
  tabPanel('MTCars', DT::dataTableOutput('mtcarz')) ,
  tabPanel('Irises', DT::dataTableOutput('iriz'))
  )
  )
  , 
  server <- (function(input, output) {
  output$mtcarz <- DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(
  mtcars,
  escape = FALSE,
  rownames = FALSE,
  options = list(
  pageLength = 25,
  autoWidth = TRUE
  )
  )
  })

  output$iriz <- DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(
  iris,
  escape = FALSE,
  rownames = FALSE,
  options = list(
  pageLength = 25,
  autoWidth = TRUE
  )
  )
  })
  })

)
```
````

but when I use the rmarkdown::render on it, the HTML page gives me the expected framework (title, etc), but with none of the tabs/dataframes in it.

I'm using v.1 of DT, v.0.9.2 of rmarkdown and v.0.12.2 of shiny along with R 3.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be missing something, but I was not aware that `Shiny` apps would work without a `Shiny` server.  Will this be dynamic?  If not, you could just do something like this.

````
```{r echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
library(shiny)
navbarPage(
  title = 'Testing Saving Shiny',
  tabPanel('MTCars', DT::datatable(
    mtcars,
    escape = FALSE,
    rownames = FALSE,
    options = list(
      pageLength = 25,
      autoWidth = TRUE
    )
  )),
  tabPanel('Irises', DT::datatable(
    iris,
    escape = FALSE,
    rownames = FALSE,
    options = list(
      pageLength = 25,
      autoWidth = TRUE
    )
  ))
)
```
````